# JQuery: search and filter a table by a single column

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter

I want to search a table by the values in a single column.

The table looks like this:

```
  <table class="table main-content">
<thead>
  <td><b>Title</b></td>
  <td><b>Name</b></td>
  <td><b>State (D)</b></td>
  <td><b>Party</b></td>
  <td><b>Room</b></td>
  <td><b>Phone #</b></td>
  <td><b>Special Role(s)</b></td>
</thead>
<tbody id="congress">

  <tr>
    <td>Senator</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.alexander.senate.gov/">Alexander, Lamar</a></td>
    <td>TN</td>        
    <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
    <td>455 Dirksen</td>
    <td>(202) 224-4944</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>Senator</td>
    <td><a href="http://www.barrasso.senate.gov">Barrasso, John</a></td>
    <td>WY</td>        
    <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
    <td>307 Dirksen</td>
    <td>(202) 224-6441</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  ...
```

I want to be able to search the table by a given column, say names (index 1) or state (index 2). I've tried [jets.js](http://jets.js.org) but it only allows one instance per page while I require at least two. JQuery is preferred, JS is fine, and external libs are ok but not optimal.

Cheers!

Edit:

I've tried using the following:

```
var $rows = $('#congress tr');

        $('#stateSearch').keyup(function() {

            var val = $.trim($(this).val()).replace(/ +/g, ' ').toLowerCase();

            $rows.show().filter(function() {
                var text = $(this).text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
                return !~text.indexOf(val);
            }).hide();


        });
```

The above code searches all of the columns in the table. How can I adjust it to search only for a specific column? (By index.)

The goal is to hide all of the tr that don't match the query in the given column

Comment: What do you expect your function to return? A tr element?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to [**try to solve your own problem first**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592). Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showcasing the specific problem you are facing in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) of the site :)

Comment: @amenadiel the goal is to remove all of the tr elements that don't match the query, leaving the ones that do

Comment: [How TO - Filter/Search Table](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
function isFound(name, state)
{
   $("table tbody").find("tr").each (function(){
        var trElem = $(this);
        if (($(this).find("td:eq(1) a").text() == name) && ($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text() == state))
            return trElem;
    })
    return false;
}
```

Usage:

```
  if (tr = isFound ('Firstname Lastname', 'State'))
      tr.remove();
```

or, if you have more than one elements, use a loop for removing

```
  while (tr = isFound ('Firstname Lastname', 'State'))
      tr.remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example that will hide all rows where the *State* column (index 3) is *TN*. You can adapt it as you need:

```
$('td:nth-child(3)').each (function(){
    if( $(this).val() == 'TN' )
        $(this).parent().hide();
});
```

Another easy solution would be to use [Datatables](https://datatables.net), which have a built-in search feature and [methods to search by column](https://datatables.net/reference/api/column().search()). It may be overkill for your project, but take a look anyway for the future.

Comment: I found it was necessary to do: if( $(this)[0].innerText === 'TN' )

Answer (score 0):

[DataTables Example](https://datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter.html)

You could reinvent the wheel, but it's probably better to just use DataTables unless you have an expressed need to do otherwise:

```js
var $table = $('table');

// Setup - add a text input to each footer cell
$table.find('tfoot th').filter(':eq(1),:eq(2)').css('visibility', 'visible').each(function() {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $(this).html('<input type="text" placeholder="Search ' + title + '" />');
});

// DataTable
var table = $table.DataTable({
  lengthChange: false
});

// Apply the search
table.columns().every(function() {
  var col = this;
  $('input', this.footer()).on('keyup change', function() {
    if (col.search() !== this.value)
      col.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```

```css
table tfoot tr th {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.13/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/bs-3.3.7/jq-2.2.4/dt-1.10.13/r-2.1.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-striped main-content">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>State (D)</th>
      <th>Party</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Phone #</th>
      <th>Special Role(s)</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Title</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>State (D)</th>
      <th>Party</th>
      <th>Room</th>
      <th>Phone #</th>
      <th>Special Role(s)</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody id="congress">
    <tr>
      <td>Senator</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.alexander.senate.gov/">Alexander, Lamar</a></td>
      <td>TN</td>
      <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
      <td>455 Dirksen</td>
      <td>(202) 224-4944</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Senator</td>
      <td><a href="http://www.barrasso.senate.gov">Barrasso, John</a></td>
      <td>WY</td>
      <td class="republican">Rep.</td>
      <td>307 Dirksen</td>
      <td>(202) 224-6441</td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: it seems like this searches the whole table...I'm trying to search just one column. Can datatables do this?

Comment: @werdna3232 Yes, I updated to an example provided on the site.  Any more customization, I suggest looking through the documentation or posting a new question once you've made an attempt.

Comment: Recommended to make the snippet render full page (the custom searches are in the table footer, which may not be visible on vertically challenged desktops)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var text = $(this).find('td:eq(1),td:eq(2)').text().replace(/\s+/g, ' ').toLowerCase();
```